# jQuery Validate select on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate plugin in my forms and I need to validate selects when users select any option to display the error immediately, now I'm using 'onfocusout' option for inputs and textareas, but obviously is not a good practice to wait for focus out when using a select.

If it helps in something, here's the code that I'm using right now to validate my forms:

```
$('form#cars').validate({
    onfocusout: function(e){
        this.element(e);
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'error help-inline',
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass){
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        $(element).closest('.control-group').addClass(errorClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass){
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass(errorClass);
    },
    messages: {
        'vehicle_city': 'Debes especificar la cuidad donde circula tu auto.'
    }
});
```

Someone knows the method to do what I want? Is there a way?

Comment: You have not shown your HTML, explained your rules or the purpose.  If the user makes a selection, what error is supposed to display?   Generally on a select, since you already control the format of the data, the only validation is whether making a selection is required.

Comment: See this jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/z75EZ/  ~  What are you expecting to happen differently?

Comment: @Sparky I want to validate the field immediately when the users selects any option in the select, not when the users submit the form.

Comment: You already said that in your question.  It makes no sense.  The user can't edit the data in each select option so what possible validation rule are you using besides `required`?  And if the user makes a selection, `required` is satisfied and you wouldn't get an error message anyway.   So again, please explain how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').on("change", function(){
    var optionVal = $(this + " option:selected")
});
```

Comment: I think if you set a scope on your DOMQuery it's better.
`var optionVal = $("option:selected", this);`
or
`var optionVal = $(this).find("option:selected");`

Comment: I don't know the relationship between the code you posted and the jQuery validate plugin with the code I posted. Can you explain me? Also I don't know 'input[type="select"]', is 'select'

Comment: @cristiangrojas You would have to add the above into your validation script as another part of validation

Comment: There is no such HTML element as `input type="select"`... it's just a `<select>` element.

Comment: I also agree with the OP's comment.  This answer seems to be very disconnected from the question.